# how to create a link to google search and pass a keyword

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hey I'm trying to creare a link that passes the link's text directly to a google search. For example my link is "fishing tips", when it is pressed a new page shows up with google search results for "fishing tips". I tried this, but it won't work. Thx for your time!

```
link_to "fishing tips", "http://www.google.com/search", :query => "fishing tips", :target => "_blank", :method => :get
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make your request as "http://www.google.com/search?q=fishing+tips" instead of giving the query separately.

so it goes like

```
http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q={YOUR_QUERY_HERE}
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get this to work in Google Sheets, however I did find a solution.

Specifically I needed to take a string from a cell in Sheets and embed it in a link that launched a Google search on that string.

The link code above is correct, in my case as follows:

```
="https://www.google.com/search?q="&A2
```

where `A2` is the field containing the query string.

However the key finding was that the query string has to be parsed of blank spaces. Spaces must be replaced with `%20` in order to function as a clickable link in Google Sheets.

The resulting formula that works is:

```
="https://www.google.com/search?q="&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","%20")
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Thats the way I needed it. Works fine

```
link_to google_query, "http://www.google.de/search?q=#{google_query}", :target => "_blank"
```